# Cómo corregir el error Return type required, Unexpected return value

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo java y estoy haciendo este código pero me da una serie de errores como he especificado en el título:

> ERROR: RETURN TYPE REQUIERED//ERROR: UNEXPECTED RETURN VALUE

"return type requiered"--> este me da en la línea justo donde pone "public static sumaArrayR", y el otro error me da en el las líneas de código justo debajo.

```
package t05p04;

public class T05p04 {
    
    public static int factorialR(int n) {
    
    if (n == 0){
        return 2;
    }else{
        return n * factorialR(--n);  
    }
}

    public static int multiplicacionR(int n, int m){
        if (m == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        if (m == 1){
            return n;
        }else{
            return n + multiplicacionR(n, m - 1);
        }
      
    }
   

    public static int divisionR(int n, int m) {
    
        if (m > n) {
         return 0;
        }else{
            return 1 + divisionR(n - m, m);
    }
}
    
    public static int divisionI(int n, int m) {
        int c = 0;
        n = n - m;
        c++;
       return 0;
    }
    
    public static int fibonacciR(int n) {
        if (n == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1;
        }else{
            return fibonacciR(n - 1) + fibonacciR(n - 2);
        }
        }
    public static int fibonacciI(int n){
        int actual = 0, ant1 = 1, ant2 = 1;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1){
            actual = 1;
        }else{
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
                actual = ant1 + ant2;
                ant2 = ant1;
                ant1 = actual;
            }
        }
    
    public static sumaArrayR(int a[], int n) {
        if(n == 1){
            return a[n - 1];
        }else{
            return sumaArrayR(a, n - 1) + a[n - 1];
        }
            
        }
    }
```

El error me lo da al hacer SumaArrayR (en esas líneas es cuando me da el error).

Comment: no estas especificando que te debe devolver ese metodo,detente a leer como lo estas declarando ..no falta algo?

Comment: lo mismo en tu método  ```fibonacci``` que regresa??

Comment: Las funciones se definen con un tipo de retorno. Por el código, supondré que debería ser `int`.